# How do I find tart pans like these?

Tags: baking, lemon, blind-baking

I want to make a lemon tart, but I want tins with straight walls, like the ones in this image.

[image: screenshot]

How would I find them - is there a name I can look for? I've been unable to find them online (and they need to be shippable to Australia).

Comment: I would have proposed Bed Bath and Beyond, but googling that for Australia got me here: http://yanksdownunder.net/topic/461876/1/  Oops :S

Comment: Meta discussion on sourcing questions:  http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1292/what-types-of-sourcing-questions-should-be-allowed-revisit-march-2013-plea

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ This one's a bit of an XY problem - the OP asked where to find them, but judging by the new answer, the real problem was that they didn't know what to call them. I'm tempted to just edit it to suit the new answer.

Comment: @Jefromi This is a tricky one... I am persuaded by Aaronut's argument that we should not let the quality of the answers determine our disposition of the question.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ But we can change the question; community editing is available for a reason, and I find it's very helpful to have the attitude "what do I think of this question in its best possible form", then edit it to that form if it makes a difference. In this case, it's the difference between "where do I find X" and "how do I find X", analogous to the difference between "what's a good stand mixer" and "how do I evaluate a stand mixer."

Comment: In any case, I edited it, and am inclined to leave it in the new form, but if others want to vote to close that's cool!

Answer (score 9):

First, those are not a "tin" which may explain why you've had trouble finding them. They are individual tart rings which must be placed on a baking sheet. Sometimes they're called flan rings or, if they're larger, cake rings.

If you do a Google search with [Australia "tart ring"](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=Australia%20%22tart%20ring%22&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44011176,d.b2U&biw=1055&bih=524&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=N&tab=iw&ei=c9xJUY_tHsbN2QWY4IHIBQ) you'll see that plenty of baking supply businesses in AU sell them.

Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice, Kate!

Answer (score 2):

Amazon seems to have quite a bit of choice. For instance:

[Mini Cheesecake Pan](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0006IW02M)

[6-Inch Mini Pie Pan](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001IZZGPK)

[Straight-sided Muffin/Cornbread Pan](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00063RX60)

Alternatively maybe these [cookie cutters](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004S1CI) could do?

Answer (score 2):

Those are English Muffin rings. Do a search for them. Most are 3.25'-3.75'diameter. You can usually get 4 of them for about $6-$7 plus shipping. Many are made by fox river

Answer (score 1):

Those are muffin rings. If you are in the USA you can get them 4 for $7 at Walmart. They carry Norpro and Fox Run.

Some people call them flan rings but the muffin rings are exactly the same and much cheaper.